# Perl get all values from hahes inside of array

Tags: perl, hash

I`m really struggling with Perl and I need to solve this topic. I Have a rest api response that I converted to json, Dumper shows something like this:

```
 VAR1= [
        {
            "id":"abc",
            "type":"info",
            "profile":
                    {"name":"Adam",
                    "description":"Adam description"}
        },
        {
            "id":"efg",
            "type":"info",
            "profile":
                    {"name":"Jean",
                    "description":"Jean description"}
        },
        {
            "id":"hjk",
            "type":"info",
            "profile":
                    {"name":"Jack",
                    "description":"Jack description"}
        },   
    ]
```

What I need is to **iterate over each "name"** and check if value is Jean. I wanted to iterate over hashes inside of array, but each time it will only store first hash, not all of them.
What I`m trying and failing:

```
# my json gather, Dumper is shown above.
my $result_json = JSON::from_json($rest->GET( $host,  $headers )->{_res}->decoded_content);
# I`ve tried many things to get all hashes, but either error, or single hash, or single value:
my $list = $result_json->[0];
my $list2 = $result_json->[0]->{'profile'};
my $list3 = @result_json->[0];
my $list4 = @result_json->[0]->{'profile'};
my $list5 = @result_json;
my $list5 = @result_json->{'profile'}; # this throws error
my $list6 = @result_json->[0]->{'profile'}->{'name'};
my $list7 = $result_json->[0]->{'profile'}->{'name'};
# and maybe more combinations... its just an example.

foreach my $i (<lists above>){
    print $i;
};
```

Any idea how to set it up properly and iterate over each "name"?

Comment: *Dumper shows something like this* 1) Which "Dumper" is this? Did you mean Data::Dumper's Dumper? That would not print json. And also that does not parse as json. But it would print `$VAR1`. 2) "something like this"? That's not good enough. Show it exactly as it is printed. And also show the code that prints it. Preferably also include a test case.

Comment: I don't get it what the problem is.  Does `$list7` not print a name?   If it does, then iterate over the array elements, `@$result_json`, instead of just picking the first one (`->[0]`), and for each get `->{profile}{name}`.  But if `$list7` isn't one of the names then something else is wrong and you should post a full example

Comment: In your "_something like_" JSON (Dumper's output) that last comma cannot be there.  I suggest you edit the question an show the exact Dumper output.  (If it is much bigger and you need to shorten it make sure to remove the comma after the last `{}` since a valid JSON string can't have a loose comma on the last element like that!)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the call to [JSON::from_json](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#from_json) shown in the code smaple is indeed given the JSON string shown as a `Dumper` output,<sup>†</sup> that `$result_json` is an array reference so iterate over its elements (hash references)

```
foreach my $hr (@{ $result_json }) {
    say "profile name: ", $hr->{profile}{name};
}
```

---

<sup>†</sup> That last comma in the supposed `Dumper`'s output can't actually be there, so I removed it to use the rest as a sample JSON for testing